# How do I get a particular value from a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a particular value form a loop like in form of an array. With the example below

```
var text = "";

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 3) continue;
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Result:

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 4
The number is 5
The number is 6
The number is 7
The number is 8
The number is 9
```

But I need to get a particular number from the loop like:

```
text += "The 5th number is " + i[5] + "<br>";
```

The result of i[5] is undefined. How can i do this correctly?

Comment: i is a integer not an array you can't use that.

Comment: do check inside loop as if (i == 5) { alert (" This is 5");}

Comment: What do you expect your `i` to contain? It's only the current index, a number, it will never be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` is a simple `string` and not an array that's why you're unable to access with `array[index]`. You better use array or

you can simply `split` your string with `<br>`, this will give you an array. Now you'll be able to use `arr[index]` on it

like

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
};

console.log("5th number is "+text.split("<br>")[4])
```

Answer (score 1):

> The result of i[5] is undefined.

That's because `i` variable is numerical, it's not an `array`.

> But I need to get a particular number from the loop

You can do this by creating an array.

```js
var text = "";
var i;
var indexes = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  indexes.push(i)
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The number is " + indexes[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the items you need to iterate and then you can access the index by `array[index]` as you mentioned.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
for(var b in a) {
    console.log(b);
    console.log(a[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the number in the list, you can add a new variable called `number` for example. This variable will be increased whenever it is used in the `for-loop` to print something, like this:

```
var text = "";
var i;
var number = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The"+ (number++) +"th number is " + i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

This will print for each line:
`The xth number is i`

*I know that this code does not display a gramatically correct example for the first, second and third number, but I wanted to display the train of thoughts behind this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a index from an variable. That is not an array. So, You can get the particular number by just using the index as in the example

```js
var text = "";
var i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 if (i === 3) { 
 text = "The "+i+"th number is " + i + "<br>";
 break; }
 
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```